# iOS app's home page not showing at first building time

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating an iOS contact app using swift. I have imported **ContactsUI**. I am trying to parse **CNContact** items using **CNContactFetchRequest**. when I try to build, it shows a white screen instate of home page (contact list in table view). 
*After bringing the app in background a alert shown for importing contacts. But this alert should show first time.* 
Why?

My code:

```
if CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts) == .NotDetermined { 
    store.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts, completionHandler: { (authorized: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in if authorized { self.ContactArr = self.createContactArr(contactCN) } }) 
} 
else if CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts) == .Authorized { 
self.ContactArr = self.createContactArr(contactCN) }

let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullN‌​ame), CNContactImageDataKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNContactUr‌​lAddressesKey,CNCont‌​actNoteKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactPostalAddressesKey] 
let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch) var contacts = [CNContact]() do { try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (let contact, let stop) -> Void in contacts.append(contact) }) }
```

I need the solution so that I need not to go to the background mode for going to the home page.

Comment: show some code how you are doing.

Comment: if CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts) == .NotDetermined {
                store.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts, completionHandler: { (authorized: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if authorized {
                        self.ContactArr = self.createContactArr(contactCN)
                    }
                })
            } else if CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts) == .Authorized {
                self.ContactArr = self.createContactArr(contactCN)
            }

Comment: let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName),
            CNContactImageDataKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNContactUrlAddressesKey,CNContactNoteKey,
            CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactPostalAddressesKey]
        let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
        var contacts = [CNContact]()
        do {
            try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (let contact, let stop) -> Void in
                contacts.append(contact)
            })
        }

Comment: just edit this code in you ques not here.

Comment: Have you checked that your view is marked as the initial view?

Comment: Yah , spliteView has been marked as initial view.